# extend abstract class issue - javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, abstract, extend

I need to extend an abstract class in javascript.
I've buy the Javascript The Definitive Guide - O'Reilly
there are some examples of OOP in js.
I've tried to execute one of the example to extends an abstract class,
but i receive the "AbstractSet.extend is not a function".
Can someone help me to understand the problem?
Thanks

```
function abstractmethod() { throw new Error("abstract method"); }

function AbstractSet() { throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract classes");}
AbstractSet.prototype.contains = abstractmethod;

var NotSet = AbstractSet.extend(
    function NotSet(set) { this.set = set; },
    {
        contains: function(x) { return !this.set.contains(x); },
        toString: function(x) { return "~" + this.set.toString(); },
        equals: function(that) {
            return that instanceof NotSet && this.set.equals(that.set);
        }
    }
);
```

--- Firebug console
AbstractSet.extend is not a function
equals: function(that) {

Answer (score 1):

There is no vanilla JavaScript `extend` method, hence the error.

Is this code copied directly from the book? Could the author be referring to [jQuery's extend method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)?

Comment: No, is in the "Core Javascript" section :( I think they are related to ecmascript 5 and my browser (FF 10.0.1) is full ecmascript 5 compliant. (as seen on http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) Thanks for the answare. :-)

Comment: What is this I don't even. `extend` is most certainly not in any JavaScript implementation, not even ES5. `extend` is typically added by libraries to coat the prototype chain (a js feature many consider to be ugly; I do not, but to each his own) with syntactic sugar.